# How to fix "Failed to read/write NVM/MEC file" error with PCSX2 emulator?

Tags: technical-issues, emulation, pcsx2

I have problem with my PCSX2 v. 1.6.0. When I try to start any game it, I get this error message:

`Failed to read/write NVM/MEC file. Check your BIOS setup permission settings.`

Do you know how can I resolve this error?

Comment: What directory is your PCSX2 program installed in?

Comment: @nightsurfer It is in : ```"C:\Users\leviathan\Documents\PCSX2 1.6.0"```

Comment: The one suggestion I see is to try installing PCSX2 in your C:\ folder, in a directory labeled PCSX2. There may be some weird permissions issues with the program and required directories living in your users folder.

Comment: @nightsurfer Could only move PCSX2 to  C:\ PCSX2 help? Or should I uninstall and reinstall it again?

Comment: I would do a full reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reinstalled it and placed it into `C:\PCSX2` folder. And it worked.